# How to get reflection data on class mentioned in macro definition?

Tags: scala, reflection, macros

I'm using **white box macro annotations** for code generation. And I'd like **step beyond trivial quasiquote substitution** and decide macros basing on extra information:

- check actual types of terms
- find all members for a trait including inherited

I understand that currently processed file is yet not available for reflection when macro expansion is called. It remains in AST form.

But, all dependent files should be already compiled by that time. So, if AST passed to a macro definition has type named `MyType`, that type should already be declared somewhere. The sad news is that `MyType` may be an alias introduced in import statement.

So, I figured the following problems should be solved to make rich macros:

1. From given term calculate its canonical name
2. Check if that name is defined in the current file and get corresponding SymTree
3. In the other case take project classpath containing already compiled files and search canonical name in them.

And, I have no clue how to approach each of the tasks. Could you suggest some way out of there?

---

### Code example

Pretty long code example, but still minimal. Programming macroses is quite verbose

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros

import scala.reflect.macros.Context
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.annotation.compileTimeOnly

import scala.collection.mutable.Buffer

trait Companion {
  val ribbon : Array[Int]
}

trait Holder {
  sealed trait AnyNode {
    private[Holder] var _index : Int = 0
    def index : Int = _index

    //example use of companion
    def next : AnyNode =
      nodes( companion.ribbon(_index) )
  }

  class Node[T](default : T) extends AnyNode {
    private var _value : T = default
    def value : T = _value
    def value_=(nv : T) = {
      _value = nv
    }
    override def toString : String = s"Node( ${this._value} )"
  }

  def companion : Companion // override in macros
  protected val nodes : Array[AnyNode] // override in macros

  // accessors for generated subTrait
  protected def placeNode(node : AnyNode, position : Int) {
    node._index = position
    nodes(position) = node
  }

  //debug output
  def printNodes : String = "nodes: " + nodes.mkString("; ")
}

@compileTimeOnly("enable macro paradise to expand macro annotations")
class fillHolder extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*) : Any = macro Implementation.fillHolder
}

class Implementation[C <: Context](val c : C) {
  import c.universe._

  lazy val typeNode = TypeName("Node")
  lazy val typeAnyNode = TypeName("AnyNode")
  lazy val typeCompanion = TypeName("Companion")
  lazy val typeHolder = TypeName("Holder")
  lazy val termCompanion = TermName("companion")
  lazy val termNodes = TermName("nodes")
  lazy val termRibbon = TermName("ribbon")
  lazy val termPlaceNode = TermName("placeNode")

  lazy val position = c.enclosingPosition

  def error(msg : String) =
    c.error(position, msg)
  def info(msg : String) =
    c.info(position, msg, true)
  def warn(msg : String) =
    c.warning(position, msg)

  def escape = c.Expr[Any](EmptyTree)

  def makeCompanion(name : TypeName) : ModuleDef = {
    val tname = name.toTermName
    q"object $tname extends $typeCompanion"
  }

  val extractHolder : PartialFunction[List[Tree], (ClassDef, ModuleDef)] = {
    case (holder : ClassDef) :: Nil => ( holder, makeCompanion(holder.name) )
    case (holder : ClassDef) :: (comp : ModuleDef) :: Nil => ( holder, comp )
  }

  def detectMethod(impl : Template, name : TermName) : Boolean = {
    impl.body.exists {
      case vd : ValDef => vd.name == name
      case dd : DefDef => dd.name == name
      case _ => false
    }
  }

  def detectMethodConflict(impl : Template, name : TermName) : Boolean = {
    val res = detectMethod(impl, name)
    if (res)
      error(s"name conflict, member $name is already defined")
    ! res
  }

  def requireParent(impl : Template, name : TypeName) : Boolean = {
    if (! impl.parents.exists(Ident(name) equalsStructure _)) {
      error(s"could not prove $name inheritance")
      false
    } else
      true
  }

  def checkHolder(holder : Template) : Boolean = {
    requireParent(holder, typeHolder) &
    detectMethodConflict(holder, termCompanion) &
    detectMethodConflict(holder, termNodes)
  }

  def checkCompanion(comp : Template) : Boolean = {
    requireParent(comp, typeCompanion) &
    detectMethodConflict(comp, termRibbon)
  }

  def detectNode(tree : Tree) : Boolean = tree match {
    case Apply( Select( New(Ident(tp)), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR ), _ ) => tp == typeNode
    case Apply( Select( New(AppliedTypeTree(Ident(tp), _)), termNames.CONSTRUCTOR ), _ ) => tp == typeNode
    case _ => false
  }

  def unwindBlock(expr : Tree) : Tree = expr match {
    case Block(_, last) => unwindBlock(last)
    case other => other
  }

  def extractNode(tree : Tree) : Option[TermName] = tree match {
    case ValDef(_, name, _, rhs) if detectNode(unwindBlock(rhs)) => Some(name)
    case _ => None
  }

  def process(source : Array[Int]) : Unit = { //side effecting on the source
    val len =  source.length - 1
    for (i <- 0 until len)
      source(i) = source(i+1)
    source(len) = 0
  }

  def substituteBody(classDef : ClassDef, body : Seq[Tree]) : ClassDef = {
    val impl = classDef.impl
    ClassDef( classDef.mods, classDef.name, classDef.tparams,
      Template(impl.parents, impl.self, body.toList) )
  }
  def substituteBody(moduleDef : ModuleDef, body : Seq[Tree]) : ModuleDef = {
    val impl = moduleDef.impl
    ModuleDef( moduleDef.mods, moduleDef.name,
      Template(impl.parents, impl.self, body.toList) )
  }

  def fillHolder(annottees : c.Expr[Any]*) : c.Expr[Any] = {
    val (holder, comp) = extractHolder.lift( annottees.map(_.tree).toList ).getOrElse(return escape)
    if (! (checkHolder(holder.impl) & checkCompanion(comp.impl)) )
      return escape

    val bodyHolder = holder.impl.body.to[Buffer]
    val bodyComp = comp.impl.body.to[Buffer]

    val nodes = holder.impl.body.flatMap(extractNode _)
    val compName = comp.name
    val ribbon = Range(0, nodes.length).toArray
    process(ribbon)

    bodyHolder += q"override def $termCompanion = $compName"
    bodyHolder += q"override protected val $termNodes : Array[$typeAnyNode] = new Array(${nodes.length})"
    bodyHolder ++= nodes.view.zipWithIndex.map{
      case (name, index) => q"$termPlaceNode($name, $index)"
    }
    bodyComp += q"override val $termRibbon = $ribbon"

    val genHolder = substituteBody(holder, bodyHolder)
    val genComp = substituteBody(comp, bodyComp)

    c.Expr[Any]( Block(genHolder :: genComp :: Nil, Literal(Constant(()))) )
  }

}
object Implementation {
  def impl(c : Context) : Implementation[c.type] = new Implementation[c.type](c)
  def apply(c : Context) : Implementation[c.type] = new Implementation[c.type](c)

  def fillHolder(c : Context)(annottees : c.Expr[Any]*) : c.Expr[Any] = impl(c).fillHolder(annottees: _*)
}
```

### Rationale

Sometimes you would like to declare a class which members forms significant structure. That structure is reproduced each time you instantiate the class. It would be nice to relocate this structure to a singleton and link instance member to it. There may be plenty reasons for it: large cost for computing the structure, large memory footprint of it, costly operations.

In this simplified example relation is chain connection between nodes. It is factored to companion object. All nodes could obtain the next node in the chain. To do so, they make indirect query to the companion, using macro generated table for binding concrete instances to shared structure.

*Real-world example* is [javafx css property](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/CSS+API+to+support+custom+UI+Controls). To define css property for a widget you should separately define css metadata (preferably static), css properties that are members of the widget class and link them together.

It would really be convenient to generate such singletons during compile time. The program would became less verbose and possibly costly computation (assume `Implementation.process` has O(n^3) complexity) relocated to compile time.

### Issues

I relay on lexical names to determine classes. They could easily be renamed with proper import. `requireParent` and `detectMethodConflict` would produce enexpected results. It would be much better if I could have access to semantic counterpart. But I have no clue how.

It would also be nice to use inheritance with `Holder` but my macros implementation could not process such cases where node definition is distributed among parents. I should traverse all value definitions for a class, including those defined in parents, and build common structure for them. But I have access only to name of parents, not to its reflection. So I could not extract their bodies and lookup them.

Comment: Can you share some code for what you want to achieve with Scala Macros?

Comment: @tuxdna could see appended code example